# Htaccess non www to www redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess

i'm using the following code to force non www URLs to redirect to www URLs;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, when I visit mydomain.com it does not redirect to www.mydomain.com.

I'm using Red Hat Linux and wondering if there is anything else I need to add to the htaccess to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have Mod-Rewrite enabeld in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

Change your rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks William. Still doesn't work. Wondering if it might be something on the DNS not set correctly. :/

Comment: Makes sure you have the correct ServerName and ServerAlias in you VirtualHost